# Assign unique number by specific number of rows R

Tags: r, grouping, sequence, repeat

I apologize in advance - I tried finding an answer to this already but I was having a hard time using the correct search terms, so this may be a repeat. I have a large dataset that I'm trying to assign a unique number to groups. But I need to assign a number not by a group in the other column (because they are not unique) so I need to do it by row number. So every three rows I want it to assign a sequential number so that each group of 3 is now labelling uniquely.

This is a VERY simplified version of what I have.

```
 data<-data.frame(col1="a",col2=c("species1",       "species2","species3","species1", "species2","species3", "species1", "species2","species3"))
```

As you can see for col1, it is all a's but species1 repeats 3 times, so I can't create a unique group based on that. And this is what I would like:

```
data2=data.frame(col1="a",col2=c("species1", "species2","species3","species1", "species2","species3", "species1", "species2","species3"), col3=c(1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))
```

Hopefully I explained this well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the example data is representative of your actual dataset, the following code should work:

```
data$col3 <- rep(seq_len(nrow(data)/3), each = 3)

data
#   col1     col2 col3
# 1    a species1    1
# 2    a species2    1
# 3    a species3    1
# 4    a species1    2
# 5    a species2    2
# 6    a species3    2
# 7    a species1    3
# 8    a species2    3
# 9    a species3    3
```

Comment: Just as an alternative, you can also do `rep(0:(nrow(data) - 1) %/% 3) + 1`; in any case +1

Comment: Alternately, `rep(seq_len(nrow(data)), each = 3, length.out = nrow(data))`